Contradictions with Newton's sums

$$z^3 + 2z^2 + k$$
The roots of the above cubic equation, where $k$ is a non zero constant, are denoted by
$\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. It is given that $\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 = 4$. Show that $k=-1$. Source: Madasmaths A-Level FP1 Practice Paper J, Q3 See here.

We will use the Newton sums method, so define $P_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + \gamma^n$.
Indeed
$P_3 + 2P_2 + 3k = 0$, we can then solve for $P_3$ using Vieta's formulae and this will yield $P_3 = -8-3k$.
Next $P_4 + 2P_3 + kP_1 = 0$. $P_1$ can also be evaluated by applying Vieta's formulae and this will yield $P_1 = -2$. Putting all this together we solve for $P_4$.
$$P_4 + 2(-8-3k) + k(-2) = 0$$
$$P_4 = 16 + 8k = 4$$
However solving shows that $k = -3/2$ not $-1$. Where am I going wrong?
Remarks:

Whilst solving this problem initially, I used Newton's sums incorrectly writing
$P_4 + 2P_3 + \color{red}{3}kP_1 = 0$ however solving for $P_4$ here I got the correct answer of $k=-1$.
The official solutions can be found here if this helps anyone.


" Where am I going wrong?" I don't think you are, but it's late at night and I may have made a slip. BTW it's a PractiCe paper.

The official solutions can be found here if this helps anyone, +Thanks for the spelling correction

There is a mistake in the official solution: at the end of page 3, $\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4$ is replaced with $8$ instead of $4$.

@Gonçalo This comment could be an answer, so that this post can be pulled out of the queue of unanswered questions.

Your result $(k=-3/2)$ is correct. Let me derive it in an alternative way. Applying Vieta's formulae to the cubic equation $z^3+2z^2+k=0$ we get$^{(*)}$
\begin{align}
&a+b+c = -2, \tag{1} \\
&ab+bc+ca = 0, \tag{2} \\
&abc = -k. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Squaring both sides of $(1)$ and using $(2)$ we obtain
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+2\underbrace{(ab+bc+ca)}_{=\,0}=4 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2=4. \tag{4}
$$
Let's now square both sides of $(4)$:
$$
a^4+b^4+c^4+2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)=16. \tag{5}
$$
We can compute the value of the expression in parentheses squaring $(2)$ and using $(1)$ and $(3)$:
\begin{align}
0&=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2(ab^2c+bc^2a+ca^2b) \\
&=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2abc(b+c+a) \\
&=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2(-k)(-2) \implies a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 = -4k. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Plugging $(6)$ into $(5)$, and using the fact that $a^4+b^4+c^4=4$, we finally obtain
$$
4+2(-4k)=16 \implies \boxed{k=-\frac{3}{2}}. \tag{7}
$$
The official solution arrived at the (wrong) solution $k=-1$ because it replaced $\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4$ with $8$, instead of $4$, at the end of page 3.

$^{(*)}$ I'm denoting the roots of the equation by $a,b,c$ instead of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ because the former are simpler to write.

+1 for finding the mistake in the "official solution", and helping to not leave this post unanswered.

I did it the long way and reproduced your answer.
$z^3+2z^2+k=0\implies z\in \{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$
$\beta+\gamma+\alpha = -2$
$(\beta \gamma+\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma)=0$
$k=-\alpha\beta\gamma$
$(\alpha +\beta+\gamma)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=4$
$\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4=4$
$(\alpha ^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)+8+3k=0$
$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+2\alpha \beta+2\beta\gamma+2\alpha\gamma)$
$\alpha^3+\alpha\beta^2+\alpha\gamma^2+2\alpha^2\beta+2\alpha\beta\gamma+2\alpha^2\gamma+\alpha^2\beta+\beta^3+\beta\gamma^2+2\alpha\beta^2+2\beta^2\gamma+2\alpha\beta\gamma+\alpha^2\gamma+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^3+2\alpha\beta\gamma+2\beta\gamma^2+2\alpha \gamma^2=-8$
$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+3\alpha^2\beta+3\alpha\beta^2+3\alpha\gamma^2+3\beta\gamma^2+3\gamma\beta^2+3\alpha^2\gamma+6\alpha\beta\gamma=-8$
$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+3\alpha^2(-2-\alpha)+3\beta^2(-2-\beta)+3\gamma^2(-2-\gamma)+6\alpha\beta\gamma=-8$
$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3-3\alpha^3-3\beta^3-3\gamma^3-6(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)+6\alpha\beta\gamma=-8$
$-2(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)-24-6k=-8$
$(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)+8+3k=0$
$\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4+ 2(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)+3k=0$
$4+ 2(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)-2k=0$
$2(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)+16+6k=0$
$12+6(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)-6k=0$
$28+8(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)=0$
$(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)=-7/2\implies k=-3/2$
